# Why am I getting some weird images, weird titles and weird body text from links?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to get image, title and body from link. However, I'm getting some weird images, weird titles and weird body text from the link.

Here is the strange result:

[image: Strange result]

My link:

https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2022-11-15/russia-expected-to-agree-to-extend-black-sea-grain-export-deal

My code:

```
AnyLinkPreview(
  link: "https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2022-11-15/russia-expected-to-agree-to-extend-black-sea-grain-export-deal",
),
```

Why am I getting some weird images, weird titles and weird body text from links? I would appreciate any help. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Maybe the site is using some-sort of re-captcha for human verification.

Comment: Sorry, I am not aware of it

Comment: @YeasinSheikh nevermind. But thanks for taking the time to read the question

Comment: Also try with different links, and find some others that will raise the same issue. You can also ask on their GitHub repo.

Comment: @YeasinSheikh I have used some other links before and the others worked. Ok, I'll ask on their Github repo

Comment: @YeasinSheikh I asked on their Github repository: https://github.com/sur950/any_link_preview/issues/43

Answer (score 0):

These images and texts are default values from the `AnyLinkPreview` package indicating that there has been an error. You can customize them by setting `errorWidget`, `errorTitle`, `errorBody` or `errorImage`. Here is a link to [the documentation](https://github.com/sur950/any_link_preview).